# Saving system images via Webdav remotely on windows 10

Tags: windows, vpn, backup, smb, webdav

I use the automated backup system on my Windows 10 laptop to weekly save a system image to my NAS using `smb` while on my LAN, easily accessible by mounting the NAS as `\\NAS\path\to\backup`. However, given that I am quite often not at home, I was trying to change it to be remotely accessible, via WebDAV. I have a functioning WebDAV server and I can mount it and access it remotely on Windows, but it doesn't allow me to use it as a valid target for saving system images

How could I implement this? Would hosting a VPN on my router and continuing to use `smb` be a viable solution? Are there any WebDAV/FTP based alternatives?

Comment: Have you considered the size of the image and how that affects the feasibility of this? A 4GB+ system image is not going to be reliably transferred to a remote server while traveling.

Comment: Oh no, I mean while connected abroad over lan cables and fiber, I expect upload speeds of 100 or 200 mbps. Would reliability be an issue in that situation? I'm not talking about updating via data services.